# How to reap children and exit from python multiprocessing pool

Tags: python-3.x, exception, python-multiprocessing, zombie-process

**What I'm trying to do:**

When an exception occurs after a multiprocessing pool is created, then the child processes become zombies when the parent terminates.
TO fix this I’m trapping the exception, and explicitly and reaping all the children in the pool.

**The problem is**

this causes the parent to hang, not exit and return to the terminal command line.

*This latter behaviour is unexpected and I don't understand why.  But the traceback indicates it is a problem in the pool.*

**The Question is**
why does this hang?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
 
def deadPool():
    print("Everybody out of the pool")
    active = mp.active_children()
    for a in active:
        print("reaping",a)
        a.terminate()
    print('deadpool')
   
try:
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()//2)
    print (" running with pool of ",mp.cpu_count()//2)
    p = 1/0  # intentional bug to generate exception
    
finally:
    deadPool()
```

**Here’s the invocation of this:**

```
python ~/Documents/testMp.py 
 running with pool of  4
Everybody out of the pool
reaping <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-1, started daemon)>
reaping <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-4, started daemon)>
reaping <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-2, started daemon)>
reaping <ForkProcess(ForkPoolWorker-3, started daemon)>
deadpool
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/foo/testMp.py", line 15, in <module>
    p = 1/0  # intentional bug 
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

***At this point the parent process is hung.***

pressing control-c to quit this hung process barks out the keyboard exception and gets back to the terminal prompt

```
^CError in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/foo/anaconda3/envs/jupyter2/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 265, in _run_finalizers
    finalizer()
  File "/Users/foo/anaconda3/envs/jupyter2/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 189, in __call__
    res = self._callback(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/foo/anaconda3/envs/jupyter2/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 581, in _terminate_pool
    cls._help_stuff_finish(inqueue, task_handler, len(pool))
  File "/Users/foo/anaconda3/envs/jupyter2/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 566, in _help_stuff_finish
    inqueue._rlock.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt
```

As you can see it seems to be stuck down in “_terminate_pool” so this is something to do with the multiprocess